# react-native Is it possible to push a route in Navigator by swiping gesture

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to push a route in Navigator with the gestures within Navigator? 
I assume if I use Pan responder, it will push a route after I swipe, which wont look as nice

Comment: Have you looked into preloading the routes with `initialRoutes` and then you can swipe between them?